# Find length of segment of the hypotenuse

Tags: geometry

I drew a sketch of the problem in paint.

[image: right_triangle_including_right_triangle_with_base_on_hypotenuse]

There are two $90$ degrees angles one at top, and one on the bottom line. Unfortunately I drew it poorly.

The $x$ part on the bottom is the one needed to solve the problem. 
Could you please explain the process? :)

Comment: Hint: the little and the big triangles share an angle and both are right triangles, thus they are...

Answer (score 2):

Sketch on paper. Cut the smaller triangle out  turn it and place it back such that sides coincide and hypotenuses are parallel.

By similar triangles comparison, ratio of corresponding sides of the two right triangles should be equal:

$$ \dfrac{1}{2}=\dfrac{5}{1+x} ,$$

so calculate $x$ from  this relation.

Comment: But, shouldn't the right answer be 2/1+x = sqrt(3)/5